# JSON remove quotes from number

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string

i want to convert a JSON object to string but without Quotes

Here is my code:

```
var X = JSON.stringify({...});

X = X.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, "$1:");
X = X.replace(/"true"/g, "true");
X = X.replace(/"false"/g, "false");
```

Here i remove quotes from false and true values and from property names
now i want to remove quotes form numeric values.

How can I write my regex?

Comment: To follow your logic, try `X = X.replace(/"(\d+)"/g, "$1");`.

Comment: Don't use regex for this, use the `replacer` callback of the [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function  or modify the original object before stringifying it.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the quotes? It wouldn't be JSON without the quotes and none of the JSON libraries will be able to parse it.

Comment: @bhspencer JSON supports numbers and boolean values. For example, `"5"` will be parsed as a string and `5` will be parsed as a number.

Comment: @Vohumanso you don't want to remove all quotes. Just those around the values that are strings that could be numbers?